How to make a model appear and emit spatial sound in visionOS?
Sounds simple enough. I am able to get a model to appear with Model3D however I am wanting to attach a sound to it so wherever it is in the room it is emitting sound. How would I do this?
Thank you!
Searching Apples Documentation

Spatial Audio in visionOS
Model3D is too primitive view in many aspects. To programmatically attach spatial audio to your USDZ model, use RealityView. To load audio you'll need an AudioFileResource object, and to control audio parameters you'll need an AudioPlaybackController object. For spatial sound, use mono files.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ctrl: AudioPlaybackController? = nil
    let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.2))
    let sound = Entity()
   
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            sound.spatialAudio = .init(directivity: .beam(focus: 0.5))
            sound.orientation = .init(angle: .pi, axis: [0,1,0])

            let audio = try! await AudioFileResource(named: "audio.mp3",
                                   configuration: .init(shouldLoop: true))
            ctrl = sound.prepareAudio(audio)
            
            box.addChild(sound)
            rvc.add(box)
            
            ctrl?.gain = -25.0
            ctrl?.speed = 2.0
            ctrl?.play()
        }
    }
}

